# What is the minimum bytes required for a new account?

Tags: ram-allocation

In my account balance the RAM used is 3446 bytes / quota 8148 bytes 
I guess that the BP has bought 8148 bytes and my account is using 3446.

So is it the minimum required for a new account ? Why did they use so many bytes ? Does it include transactions that are specific to the main net launch?

What is the minimum bytes required for a new account ?

Answer (score 3):

I tried 4k, it worked. I think the minimum bytes could be lower than 4k.

```
cleos system newaccount --stake-net "0.001 EOS" --stake-cpu "0.001 EOS" --buy-ram-kbytes 4
```

Comment: I've seen people use less, but everyone seems to agree that 4kb is the "safe" number; however, I'm unsure what metrics they're using to determine how it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

Anything less than 2,978 bytes fails for me. 
[Example](https://eosflare.io/tx/02B0EBAF736A64B036F3DE0C3F8C2ED7507EEAC42B4101F9ADE6A27D401FA9E3)